# Which Layout is better for my app?

Tags: android, layout

I would like to create an app that has two images side by side and two radioButtons, one down of every image. Which Layout is more suitable for this job (tableLayout, Linear or Relative..)? I have tried it with linear but the images are stacked together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of them, with different effort and cost for your application.

The easiest is probably to use a TableLayout, but it's more resourceful.

RelativeLayout is very efficient, but harder to learn and perhaps a little difficult to understand later.

I think you should go with 2 linear Layouts.

- LinearLayout (horizontal)

  - LinearLayout (vertical)

    - Image
    - Radio Button
  - LinearLayout (vertical)

    - Image
    - Radio Button

If you need the rows to be always exact same height, using TableLayout is not a bad idea too.

Comment: thanks for your answer!i have tried it with linearlayout and it works perfect but i would like to know if there is a most "recommented" way to do it!!

Comment: i have one more question if you could help me!i made one scren with these two imgs and i would like to add a button on it witch will drive to a second page when i click it.do you know how i will write it in the java file?

Comment: There is no recommended way to do it, just the way for you to get the job done quickly. ;-). Layouts are a base for future expansion and you can use any layout now (with some elements only). If you need advanced layout features, switch your layout at a later time. Android makes that easy.

Comment: Close this Q and ask a new Q.